# Removing parts of a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array $data :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 86086
    [1] => Arnel
    [2] => Paras
)
Array
(
    [0] => 86085
    [1] => Arnely
    [2] => Para
)
Array
(
    [0] => 

)
```

How do i remove the bottom array that contains no values totally so it only contains :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 86086
    [1] => Arnel
    [2] => Paras
)
Array
(
    [0] => 86085
    [1] => Arnely
    [2] => Para
)
```

I have tried using array_filter($data, strlen) and it just does this :

```
Array
(

)
```

Comment: Try `array_filter($data, 'count')` instead. In fact, you can just use `array_filter($data)` as the default callback will remove empty arrays. I suggest reading the docs carefully in future. Voting to close as a typo / no longer a problem

Comment: @Phil , i tried using array_filter($data) and it returns the this Array(), it does not remove it totally

Comment: please show your actual array. Your `print_r()` dumps don't show the structure of `$data`

Comment: As you can see here, `array_filter($data)` does actually work ~ https://3v4l.org/TNcgZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_pop() pops and returns the value of the last element of array, shortening the array by one element and will do exactly what you describe. A.

array_shift() does the opposite (removes first element from array and returns the value)

[array_pop() on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

So you can either do:

```
$firstVal = array_pop($data)
```

or just

```
array_pop($data)
```

depending on if you want the value back or not.

Comment: I think OP wants to remove the empty arrays, not necessarily the last element

Comment: Glad to help! You might also look into unset() for removing a value in the middle of an array.  For example unset($data[1]) will properly remove the middle value (if I recall correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Might help.

```
array_values(array_filter($data))
```